# How to write C# 5 async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I have the following scenario:
When a command is inputted (for test, it's a console application, when it's ready, I hope it will be a WebService) I execute some code, and when further user input is needed, I return to the command interpreter immediately. When the new input is given, I want processing to resume from where I left it. That sounds so much like c#5 async-await pattern, that I decided to give it a try. 
I was thinking about this:

```
public void CommandParser()
{
   while(true)
   { 
      string s = Console.ReadLine();
      if (s == "do_something")
         Execute();
      else if (s == "give_parameters")
         SetParameters();
      //... 
   }
}
MySettings input;
public async void Execute()
{
  //do stuff here
  MyResult result = null
  if (/*input needed*/){
     input = new MySetting();
     result = await input.Calculate();
  }
  else { /* fill result synchronously*/}
  //do something with result here

}

public void SetParameters()
{
   if (input!=null)
      input.UseThis("something"); //now it can return from await
}
```

Now my question is, how to write MySettings.Calculate and MySettings.UseThis? How to return a Task from the first and how to signal readyness from the second? I've tried with many factory methods for Task, but I can't find the right one! Please help!

Comment: Its not directly relavant to your question, but how do you have c# 5?

Comment: i'm trying to use the async ctp: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d7ccfefa-123a-40e5-8ed5-8d2edd68acf4&displaylang=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx). That will build a task for you, and you can call `SetResult` or `SetException` on the source, which will signal the task appropriately.

That's what I've used to [implement `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T>` for Eduasync](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/15/eduasync-part-4-filling-in-asynctaskmethodbuilder-lt-t-gt.aspx) - so you can look at that for an example.

You'd need to either set up the `TaskCompletionSource` beforehand or perform some other coordination so that `input.Calculate` and `UseThis` both know about the same object - but then `Calculate` would just return `completionSource.Task`, and `UseThis` would call `completionSource.SetResult`.

Bear in mind that when you call `SetResult`, the async method will keep going on a different thread-pool thread if you're using a console app (or web service) - so you'd no doubt want to create a *different* `TaskCompletionSource` for the main loop to then use for the next round, as it were.

Comment: thanks, it looks very promising. I'll try implement my actual code, then check back for the accept.

Comment: Quick question though, I have installed the CTP, but await doesn't seem to compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TDaver: What errors are you getting? If the CTP installed cleanly, the compiler should have been changed appropriately...

Comment: I've since then figured out that my problem is that I have some post-sp1 update installed, and it blocks the async ctp. My problem is I don't know what update is that, so right now I'm uninstalling every .net and vs update I can find....