# Async exception handling with void

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm using Async CTP to write an IO heavy console app. But I'm having problems with exceptions.

```
public static void Main()
{
   while (true) {
     try{
         myobj.DoSomething(null);
     }
     catch(Exception){}
     Console.Write("done");
     //...
   }
}

//...
public async void DoSomething(string p)
{
   if (p==null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
   else await SomeAsyncMethod();
}
```

And the following happens: "done" gets written to the console, then I get the exception in the debugger, then I press continue **my program exists**.
What gives?

Comment: Why not use public async Task DoSomething(string p) instead (and await it)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call `DoSomething()` it basically creates a `Task` under the hood and starts that `Task`. Since you had a `void` signature, there is no `Task` object to signal back or that you could have blocked on, so execution fell straight through to done. Meanwhile the task throws an exception, which nobody is catching, which, I suspect, is why your program terminates.

I think the behavior you wanted is more like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
   while (true) {
     var t = myobj.DoSomething(null);
     t.Wait();
     if(t.HasException) {
       break;
     }
   }
   Console.Write("done");
   //...
  }
}

//...
public async Task DoSomething(string p)
{
  if (p==null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
  else await SomeAsyncMethod();
}
```

This will block on each `DoSomething` until it's done and exit the loop if `DoSomething` threw. Of course, then you are not really doing anything async. But from the pseudo code, i can't quite tell what you wanted to happen asynchronously.

Main take-away: Using `void` for an async method means that you loose the ability to get the exception unless you are `await`ing that async method. As a sync call it basically just schedules work and the outcome disappears into the ether.

Comment: I cannot call t.Wait(), as it blocks the main Console thread, so I cannot input anything else, so the SomeAsyncMethod will never finish (for my usage see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145246/how-to-write-c-5-async)

Comment: But I've figured it out! I don't WAIT my tasks, I put them into a list, and after each IO operation (when they can throw exceptions) I check the list if any of the tasks faulted!

Comment: Yeah, it's usually best to fire up all the Tasks, collect them in a list and then to a TaskEx.WhenAll(listOfTasks).Wait() when you want to collect all the work

Comment: I think your `t.HasException` in your code will never return `true`, because `Wait()` throws `AggregateException` if the code in the task threw an exception.

Answer (score 33):

If you give your Console application an async-compatible context (e.g., `AsyncContext` ([docs](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext), [source](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs)) from my AsyncEx library), then you can catch exceptions that propogate out of that context, even from `async void` methods:

```
public static void Main()
{
  try
  {
    AsyncContext.Run(() => myobj.DoSomething(null));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
  Console.Write("done");
}

public async void DoSomething(string p)
{
  if (p==null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
  else await SomeAsyncMethod();
}
```