# Difference between Task and void methods (Non Async)

Tags: c#, task

What are the differences between these two methods?

```
public void DoWork() {}
public Task DoWork() {}
```

Note I am not using async.

Comment: One of them returns a `Task` instance, the other one doesn't return anything...

Comment: I think it would depend on the bodies of the `DoWork` methods. Is the second one actually returning a `Task` instance? How is that instance being created? What is the body of the void method? Does it involve asynchronous activity also? I think you may want to add some clarification to your question to get a clear answer.

Comment: Also, by not using async...do you mean this is before .Net 4.5 and thus async/await is not available to you? (I had this experience before when our company could not upgrade from .Net 4.0)

Comment: No, I mean in .NET 4.5+ where async is available, but not using it.

Comment: Also, If you were to assume you do an Async operation such as `Task.Run(() => lol)`, assume you do it in **both**, and so what is the difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public Task DoWork() {}` can be awaited in an async call

`public void DoWork() {}` don't

Comment: I think that pretty much sums it up.  But as ibgib brings up: What's in the body?  The question then is: What if an awaitable (like `Task.Run`) is called from with **both** bodies, do any new difference arise from that situation?  Maybe `Task` suddenly transforms into a magical unicorn?

Comment: awaitable means: you can call the method from an async call and wait for the method completes. if you don't needs that... just use void not Task

Comment: Right, you can use an awaitable in a non-async method.  You just can't await it.  I was just transferring ibgib's paraphrased concern to here.  Sounds like it is of no consequence.

Comment: Ouch. So this *is* an async/await question. Doh! I spent a couple years where they wouldn't upgrade, so I had to create my own personal async framework around TPL!

Comment: And since it is an async question, another key point to remember is that if you end up with `public async void DoWork` vs `public async Task DoWork`, you will lose any exception handling awesomeness in try..catch blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284267/async-exception-handling-with-void