# What are the differences between `async void` (with no await) vs `void`

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Taken from [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on async await by Stephen Cleary:

**Figure 2 Exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch**

```
private async void ThrowExceptionAsync()
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
public void AsyncVoidExceptions_CannotBeCaughtByCatch()
{
  try
  {
    ThrowExceptionAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    // The exception is never caught here!
    throw;
  }
}
```

> ... any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started...

What does that actually mean? I wrote an extended example to try and glean more info. It has the same behaviour as Figure 2:

```
static void Main()
{

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, ex) => 
    {
        LogCurrentSynchronizationContext("AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException");
        LogException("AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException", ex.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    };

    try
    {
        try
        {
            void ThrowExceptionVoid() => throw new Exception("ThrowExceptionVoid");

            ThrowExceptionVoid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException("AsyncMain - Catch - ThrowExceptionVoid", ex);
        }

        try
        {
            // CS1998 C# This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. 
            async void ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid() => throw new Exception("ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid");

            ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid();
        }
        // exception cannot be caught, despite the code running synchronously.
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            LogException("AsyncMain - Catch - ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid", ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException("Main", ex);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void LogCurrentSynchronizationContext(string prefix)
    => Debug.WriteLine($"{prefix} - " +
        $"CurrentSynchronizationContext: {SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType().Name} " +
        $"- {SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetHashCode()}");

private static void LogException(string prefix, Exception ex)
    => Debug.WriteLine($"{prefix} - Exception - {ex.Message}");
```

Debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in ConsoleApp3.dll
AsyncMain - Catch - ThrowExceptionVoid - Exception - ThrowExceptionVoid
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in ConsoleApp3.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ConsoleApp3.dll but was not handled in user code
ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - CurrentSynchronizationContext:  - 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - Exception - ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid
The thread 0x1c70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
ThrowExceptionAsyncVoid
The program '[18584] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**I want more details**

- If there is no current synchronization context (as in my example), where is the exception raised?
- What are the differences between `async void` (with no `await`) and `void`

  - The compiler warns `CS1998 C# This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.`
  - If it runs synchronously with no `await`, why is it behaving differently from simply `void`?
  - Does `async Task` with no `await` also behave differently from `Task`?
- What are the differences in compiler behaviour between `async void` and `async Task`. Is a `Task` object really created under-the-hood for `async void` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284502/5032032)?

***Edit.*** To be clear, this isn't a question about best practices -  it is a question about compiler / runtime implementation.

Comment: Well yes, if you *do* make a method `async` with no `await` expressions, it's pointless and odd. But the whole point of making a method `async` is so that you *can* use `await` expressions.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx explains about the different return types and exceptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If there is no current synchronization context (as in my example), where is the exception raised?

[By convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), when `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`, that's really the same as `SynchronizationContext.Current` equal to an instance of `new SynchronizationContext()`. In other words, "no synchronization context" is the same as the "thread pool synchronization context".

So, the behavior you're seeing is that the `async` state machine is catching the exception and then raising it directly on a thread pool thread, where it cannot be caught with `catch`.

This behavior seems odd, but think about it this way: `async void` is intended for event handlers. So consider a UI application raising an event; if it is synchronous, then any exceptions get propagated to the UI message processing loop. The `async void` behavior is intended to mimic that: any exceptions (including ones after `await`) are re-raised on the UI message processing loop. This same logic is applied to the thread pool context; e.g., exceptions from your synchronous `System.Threading.Timer` callback handler will be raised directly on the thread pool, and so will exceptions from your asynchronous `System.Threading.Timer` callback handler.

> If it runs synchronously with no await, why is it behaving differently from simply void?

The `async` state machine is handling the exceptions specially.

> Does async Task with no await also behave differently from Task?

Absolutely. `async Task` has a very similar state machine - it catches any exceptions from your code and places them on the returned `Task`. This is [one of the pitfalls in eliding `async`/`await` for non-trivial code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

> What are the differences in compiler behaviour between async void and async Task.

For the compiler, the difference is just how exceptions are handled.

The proper way to think about this is that `async Task` is a natural and appropriate language development; `async void` is a weird hack that the C#/VB team adopted to enable asynchronous events without huge backwards-compatibility issues. Other `async`/`await`-enabled languages such as F#, Python, and JavaScript have no concept of `async void`... and thus avoid all of its pitfalls.

> Is a Task object really created under-the-hood for async void as suggested here?

No.

Answer (score -1):

1. async void - It can't be awaited and it allows you to fire or forget methods
2. async Task - It can be awaited, but does not return any value
3. async Task methodName { return default(T); } - It can be awaited, and returns a value of the type T
4. void - no argument will be returned